# Using accented letters in R package documentation using bibtex and roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2, bibtex

I am developing an R package in RStudio (R version 3.6.1; RStudio version 1.2.1335) using `roxygen2` (version 6.1.1) and am using the `\insertCite{}` command together with a bibtex file in order to cite references in the documentation for individual functions. I am following the instructions [Inserting references in Rd and roxygen2 documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdpack/vignettes/Inserting_bibtex_references.pdf). Everything works fine, except when I try to include a reference with accented characters. So my REFERENCES.bib file contains the following entry:

```
@ARTICLE{Cabcdef15,
    author={John {\c C}abcdef},
    title={A title},
    journal={Journal of Applied Stuff},
    year={2015},
    volume={81},
    number={1},
    pages={100--200},
}
```

The `{\c C}` is the LaTeX command for a C-cedilla (Ç). (I also tried `\c{C}` and pasting `Ç` directly and neither resolved the issue.)

I cited this reference in the `roxygen2` preamble for my R function `myfunction` using `\insertCite{Cabcdef15}{mypackage}`. However, in the documentation output (after running `devtools::document()` and `devtools::build()`, installing the package and running `library(mypackage)` and `?myfunction`) the citation appears in my browser (Google Chrome) as (Ã‡abcdef 2015) rather than as (Çabcdef 2015).

Presumably this is an encoding issue. However, from what I read in the aforementioned instructions (under **4.4 Encoding of file REFERENCES.bib**) this should be working, provided that I have the line `Encoding: UTF-8` in the DESCRIPTION file for my R package, which I do. Hence I am stumped.

Comment: There's a lot of detail here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html that might help. Search on encoding.

Comment: Have you tried inserting the character without the encoding? Looking at some other package descriptions in Github, if an accented character shows up, it's just normal, like Ç. I think this works because of the Encoding: UTF-8 entry. Here's an example: https://github.com/EDiLD/esmisc/blob/master/DESCRIPTION. The example is an o with umlaut, but seems to be the same principle.

Comment: The character "Ç" has latin1 encoding, as can be verified in R with Encoding("Ç"). I have gone through the R-exts manual material on encoding but still don't have a solution. I added `@encoding UTF-8` to the roxygen2 preamble to the function but this had no effect.

Comment: Do you have any of the package on github?

Comment: Final suggestions, maybe try the bibentry function as suggested in the R-extensions manual section 1.9. Or ask the package develop experts here: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel

Comment: My package is not on github at this point as it's in very early stages of development. I hope to eventually get it there. If I put a "Ç" in the roxygen2 object documentation text it does show up, similar to your github example above. The problem is only to get a "Ç" from the bibtex file to show up in documentation using the `\insertCite{}` command in `roxygen2`. I think that I will try posting this problem at RStudio Community.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong suspicion you are using a Microsoft operating system.

I have code in a roxygen2 examples block which outputs accented French characters: works fine with non-French locales on MacOS and Linux: Windows makes a mess of it. I have UTF-8 in package DESCRIPTION. For me, the obvious work-around is not to use Windows for documenting the package. UTF-8 everywhere seems to work well for me, except on Windows. The R documentation links are helpful, and, in a related post, the mighty Yihui Xie [writes about this issue](https://yihui.org/en/2018/11/biggest-regret-knitr/).

This `WONTFIX` [R issue](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16064) also hints at the root cause: Windows.

A more palatable and Windows-compatible workaround is discussed in [platform specific sections](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Platform_002dspecific-sections) in Writing R Extensions.